# When does Python create new list objects for empty lists?

Tags: python, list, empty-list, object-identity

The following makes sense to me:

```
>>> [] is []
False
```

Given that lists are mutable, I would expect `[]` to be a new empty list object every time it appears in an expression. Using this explanation however, the following surprises me:

```
id([]) == id([])
True
```

Why? What is the explanation?

Comment: I would wager some nonzero sum of money that `id([]) == id([])` is not `True` on all flavors of python.  (yep, checked.)  cPython tends to reallocate memory in this way, it is an implementation detail.

Comment: @roippi I think it's actually a fluke of rapid malloc/free/malloc.  `a = []; b = []; id(a) == id(b) # This is False`

Comment: @roippi -- I would wager that there are some flavors of Python where it works sometimes and not others, depending on exactly when the GC runs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the first example, `[]` is not `[]` precisely *because* the lists are mutable. If they weren't, they could safely map to the same one without issue.

In the second example, `id([])` creates a list, gets the id, and deallocates the list. The second time around it creates a list *again*, but "puts it in the same place" because nothing much else has happened. `id` is only valid during an object's lifetime, and in this case its lifetime is virtually nil

From the [docs on id](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id):

> This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.

---

Commented disassembly:

```
   0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (id)    # load the id function
   3 BUILD_LIST               0         # create the first list
   6 CALL_FUNCTION            1         # get the id
   9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (id)    # load the id function
  12 BUILD_LIST               0         # create the second list
  15 CALL_FUNCTION            1         # get the id
  18 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)    # compare the two ids
  21 RETURN_VALUE                       # return the comparison
```

Note there is no `STORE_FAST` to retain the list. Therefore it was discarded immediately after getting passed to the `id` function.

Comment: I remember you answered the same question not quite long before ;P

Comment: not this one, maybe it's not you, but must be a duplicate

Comment: Well answered. For example in `def f(x, y): return id(x) == id(y)` where both `x` and `y` have to stay alive, `f([], [])` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Precisely. As long as their lifetimes overlap, they must by definition have unique keys.

Comment: @mhlester Can you explain why two empty tuples declared independently e.g. `a = (), b = ()` have same id? disassembly shows STORE_FAST is called twice though. Just because tuples are immutable?

Comment: @Aamir, yes: because they are immutable, they will always store the same value. If the value is always the same, why store it twice?